# Datatemplate binding itemsource inside Datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate, itemsource

I want to bind a ObservableCollection to a Itemscontrol inside a Datatemplate, that is inside another Datatemplate:

```
<ListView x:Name="list_befehlsfolge" Margin="5">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Befehlszeile}" >
            <Expander Margin="5" Header="{Binding Path=Bezeichnung,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubBefehlsliste}">
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubZeile_Text}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=text,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Binding the source to `list_befehlsfolge.Itemsource` with code behind is no problem, but how can I bind `SubBefehlsliste`?

When I create a new instance of `SubBefehlsliste` like

```
public class Befehlszeile : Position
{
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; } = "Befehlsname";
 
    // crash at this line:  
    public ObservableCollection<Position> SubBefehlsliste { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Position>();
   
    public Befehlszeile()
    {
        //  SubBefehlsliste.Add(new SubZeile_Text());
    }
}
```

it crashes with an error

> InvalidOperationException: The operation is invalid while using 'ItemsSource'. Instead, use ItemsControl.ItemsSource to access and modify items. (translated with google)

(Position is a "Mother"-class for all Datatypes like SubZeile_Text and other, to add all to a ObservableCollection)

Comment: There is a missing tag: `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` before `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubZeile_Text}">`.
Thus your DataTemplate is regarded as an element being added to `Items` collection of your items-control, which a) a DataTemplate can't be and which b) is invalid if you use `ItemSource` at the same time.
Adding `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` before and `</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` after the DataTemplate tag should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem, the Datatemplates must be inside "<ListView.Resources>" and "<ItemsControl.Resources>":

```
   <ListView x:Name="list_befehlsfolge" Margin="5">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Befehlszeile}" >
                <Expander Margin="5" Header="{Binding Path=Bezeichnung,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubBefehlsliste}">
<ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubZeile_Text}">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=text,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: The code in this answer will not work correctly.
You just repeated the code from the question at the top of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify a property for the template. So the Template you specified was an attempt to add to the ItemsControl.Items collection.
But you cannot use ItemsSource and Items at the same time.

Another incomprehensible moment: in the Sharpe code you use the `Position` class for the elements of the collection, and in the Data Template you set the `local:SubZeile_Text` type.
Which of these options is correct?

```xml
<ListView x:Name="list_befehlsfolge" Margin="5">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Befehlszeile}" >
            <Expander Margin="5" Header="{Binding Path=Bezeichnung,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubBefehlsliste}">
                    <!--Forgotten this line below-->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Position}">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=text,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**P.S.** Tip: If you don't define columns, then use a ListBox, not a ListView.